# Interface object IDbconnection

Tags: c#

Someone please explain in simple terms. I'm a relative noob. Everything I've learnt says you cannot create objects of type interface. If that's so, what's happening here?

```
IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(DataAccessHelpers.LoadConnectionString(dbName))
```

is cnn not an object?

Comment: The object is of type `SQLiteConnection` that implements the `IDbConnection`, but it alone is not an interface but rather an object.

Comment: you can assign an object that implements an interface to a reference of type interface. Here SQLiteConnection is an object that implements interface of IDbConnection. And if you think that is the power of interface that you dont know the implementation details of object but only know the functionality it performs through interface reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways you can create an object of a class which implements the stated interface (IDbConnection). However, you can see this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-interface) if you want to use this syntax and get a better understanding about the other rules regarding it (e.g. if the class implements multiple interfaces).